# Access document when I have the UID

Tags: xpages

I have a combobox on my form that loads client names from a view using the format "name | UID" - this displays the client name on the form but saves the UID in the field.

I now want to use the UID to lookup the name for the client and save it in a field on the XPage that is not visible using the following code:

```
// ignore when UID is null
if (getComponent("parentUID").getValue() == null) 
    return false;

var UID:string = getComponent("parentUID").getValue();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(UID);

// now set your fields 
document1.setValue("nachname", doc.getItemValueString ("nachname"));
document1.setValue("vorname", doc.getItemValueString ("vorname"));
```

I do this in a simple action attached to a button. The next simple action is a Save.

The code crashes with the following error:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=8, col=42: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.getDocumentByUNID(java.lang.String) null

I have copied the parentUID to a field on the document and I am getting the correct UID and the document exists in the database?

Any ideas?

PS: I am adding this to an existing application and the current document is not a response document - cannot change that unfortunately :o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found my problem - XPages returned the UID but it included a leading space. When I concatenated the values I did the following: "name | UID" i.e. I added a leading and trailing space to the pipe symbol to make the code legible - this was causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the get.Value() in your getComponent line

Try `getComponent("parentUID").getValue() == null`

My guess is that this is causing the code to run when the UID is null. This means that the code is running when it really is null, and your effort to check for that isn't working.

---

Thanks for checking that.

- Can you put in a print() statement and ensure that you have a value in the var UID.
- Another thing, please capitalize the word "String" since java classes are capitalized.

Comment: I did indeed miss the .getValue() - thanks for catching that - it hasn't helped fixing this though...  Any other ideas?